# Is there a way to unserialize an array with twig?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, twig

I have an array serialized with php, and i would like to us it in a twig template. I tried the reverse filter but it doesn't work.

```
a:3:{i:1;a:2:{s:10:"mensualite";s:4:"1500";s:4:"date";s:10:"01/01/2018";}i:2;a:2:{s:10:"mensualite";s:4:"2500";s:4:"date";s:10:"02/01/2018";}i:3;a:2:{s:10:"mensualite";s:4:"3500";s:4:"date";s:10:"03/01/2018";}}
```

Comment: Why not just use the `unserialize` function?

Comment: It doesn't existe in twig. In the controller i'm sending the whole entity so i can't really unserialize it with PHP before sending to the twig view

Comment: You're coming from your controller right?! Why not unserialize in the controller first, then pass the data to your view?

Comment: You could write a custom Twig Extension, register the extension as a service and unserialize the array...in the view you could use: {{ dump(array|TwigUnserialize) }} I would like to add the code, however the question has been marked as duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in the controller

```
foreach($entity_partiellement as $ent ){
        if(!empty($ent->getMensualite())){
            $serial = unserialize($ent->getMensualite());
            $ent->setMensualite($serial);
        }
    }
```

It's not very clean but it works